# A sinonjs stub in the "then"

Tags: javascript, sinon

I have a class A , and I want to test the eventHandler method.

```
class A () {
    eventHandler (controller) {
        controller.exec().then((() => {
            this._afterHandler();  // I can't stub it.
        }))
     // this._afterHandler();  // I can  stub it !!!
    }


    _afterHandler() {
        xxxxx...;
    }
}
```

This is my test code . I find that I can not stub the _afterHandler method. when the method in the then. but when I move the method to the "then" outside. I can stub it.

```
 it('xxxx', () => {
      const a = new A();
      const stub = sinon.stub(a,'_afterHandler');
      a.eventHandler({ exec: () => {return Promise.resolve(1)} })

      sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
    });
```

How can I stub the _afterHandler method ?? Thanks ~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*_afterHandler* is getting stubbed by Sinon.

The problem here is that *sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub)* is getting called before the stubbed *_afterHandler* - thanks to the use of promises.

---

In terms of making this testable, one option is like:

```
class A {
  eventHandler (controller) {
    return controller.exec().then(() => {
      this._afterHandler();
    })
  }

  _afterHandler() {
    xxxxx...;
  }
}
```

and the test:

```
it('xxxx', async () => {
  const a = new A();
  const stub = sinon.stub(a,'_afterHandler');
  await a.eventHandler({ exec: () => {return Promise.resolve(1)} });

  sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub);
});
```